# setText not working for a Custom Edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, settext

I am using a nice Material design edit text which I found from github: https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText

and updated the dependency section as :

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.0.3'
}
```

The edittext xml is defined as follows:

```
    <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
        android:id="@+id/device_file_location_value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint_file_location"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:met_floatingLabel="normal"
        app:met_floatingLabelText="@string/file_location"
        app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true"
        app:met_baseColor="#FCFBE3"
        app:met_primaryColor="#FCFBE3"/>
```

So I am expecting to fill the value of the edit text programatically by browsing the file system. So the edittext is clickable but not focusable and hence user cannot edit the path of file received. Now this (`device_file_location_value`) edit text is updated by a value received from other fragment(the fragment that implements the file browser) and is updated as follows in the `onCreateView` of its fragment:

```
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        String filePath = bundle.getString(FileBrowserFragment.PARAM_FILE_PATH);
        if (filePath != null) {
            filePathValue.setText(filePath);
            bundle.remove(FileBrowserFragment.PARAM_FILE_PATH);
        }
```

Somehow this is not updating the text on the UI. I have also tried using `filePathValue.invalidate()` but that didn't help either.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: @MarkKeen It did not work. But stefno's solution did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try in this way.

```
filePathValue.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    filePathValue.setText(filePath);
                }
            })
```

Comment: could you also explain why this would work. Meanwhile I will try it out. Thanks.

Comment: Because you can not modify GUI on the main thread, so in this way you create a little new thread to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Can you suggest some reading on this. I am still new to android and learning things.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261370/is-main-thread-the-same-as-ui-thread try to read this thread

Comment: Could you also look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949634/custom-progress-dialog-not-working/34949829?noredirect=1#comment57631610_34949829.