# Custom progress dialog not working

Tags: android, progressdialog

I found this nice custom progress dialog box: https://github.com/d-max/spots-dialog

and am using it as follows inside `onClick` function of the fragment (as connection to remote device is made on a button press):

```
    AlertDialog dialog = new SpotsDialog(parentActivity, R.style.custom_dialog);
    dialog.show();
    //bluetooth time consuming code.
    dialog.dismiss();
    parentActivity.loadFragment(DrawerActivity.Fragments.FILE_BROWSER, bundle, true);
```

I have defined the following in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="custom_dialog" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog">
    <item name="DialogTitleAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
    <item name="DialogTitleText">Updating…</item>
    <item name="DialogSpotColor">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
    <item name="DialogSpotCount">4</item>
</style>
```

Updated the dependencies as follows as per instructions given on the github page:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.4@aar'
}
```

I am not sure what I am missing. Any help appreciated.

EDIT: Adding relevant component from gradle:

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "edu.unm.twin_cities.graphit"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 16
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Comment: what is the problem here?

Comment: @Stefano The progress bar just does not appear. Nothing happens.

Comment: Try to look at the logs, maybe you get some error that explain why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

1. You're API level must be a higher then 15.
2. On the pre-lollipop devices DialogSpotColor item won't work. As workaround just override color in your resources. Your max level API is 16, lollipop its 21 and higher.

Try throw away the DialogSpotColor item from your style.

```
<style name="custom_dialog" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog">
<item name="DialogTitleAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
<item name="DialogTitleText">Updating…</item>
<item name="DialogSpotCount">4</item>
```

And add this line into your colors.xml:

```
<color name="spots_dialog_color">@android:color/holo_red_light</color>
```

Comment: I have minsdkversion as 15, so it should work..right? Please see the edit in the question.