# What is the Android Main/UI Thread file name?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

What is the exactly file name of the Main/UI Thread?

I know what the Main/UI Thread does, but I want to see its implementation details.

All my researches points me to this class: **ActivityThread**.

There you can see some pretty low level methods like :

- performLaunchActivity
- public static void main(String[] args)

I am confused because **ActivityThread does not** extends or even creates a Java Thread(), and it also contains a **ApplicationThread** which seems to be related to the creation of the an Application process.

So I ask:

- What is the file name where I can see the implementation details of the Main/UI Thread?